# Is it possible to retrieve media (image or video) url using projection in Linkedin's Post Api?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm trying to fetch posts belonging to a Linkedin organization. For posts that have media (image or video), I want the url of the media, not just the urn.

My parameters are as follows:

```
$params = [
     'author' => urn:li:organization:xxxxx,
     'q' => 'author',
     'count' => 15,
     'projection' => '(elements(id,commentary,content(media(id~(id,title,downloadUrl),title),multiImage,article),publishedAt,author),paging)',
];
```

I'm getting the following response (I'll just show the details of one of the posts returned):

```
"publishedAt" => 1666769109204
"author" => "urn:li:organization:xxxxx"
"content" => array:1 [▼
        "media" => array:3 [▼
          "id" => "urn:li:image:xxxxxxxxxxxx"
          "title" => ""
          "id!" => array:2 [▼
            "message" => "Unsupported URN domain: li:image"
            "status" => 501
          ]
        ]
      ]
"id" => "urn:li:share:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
"commentary" => "Some text here"
```

I need some assistance here.

Comment: Why do you want the full URL? It should be fairly easy to inspect the URN to determine if it is an image or video and then to call the Images or Videos API to get more details about the media content if needed. The standard base URLs are https://api.linkedin.com/rest/videos/{URN} and https://api.linkedin.com/rest/images/{URN}.

Comment: @Ashavan I need the full URL to be able to display the image or video to my app user i.e.,  the owner of the post can view its details (including images and videos) on my app.